# Conditional type/interface based on contents of Array

Tags: typescript, firebase

I'm trying to create an interface based on Array of strings. There is a limited amount of strings that can be passed and I have a type for all of them, which I then combine into another array, as shown here:

```
export type firestore = 'firestore';
export type auth = 'auth';
export type database = 'database';
export type storage = 'sorage';
type tech = firestore | auth | database | storage;
export type techArray = tech[];
```

Withe these definitions I'm hoping to create an Interface that will have only given smaller interfaces/types.

```
export const CreateFirebaseContext = (
    firebaseConfig: firebaseConfigType,
    tech: techArray,
) => {
    type hooksCollectionType = {
        firestore: tech.includes('firestore') ? firestoreType : never, // this is the idea I'm exploring which is obviously broken; firestoreType is that smaller interface type i mentioned earlier, which I'm yet to create
        database: tech
    }
};
```

I'm sorry if the idea is completely broken. I'm doing this so I make sure I dont include extra libraries for firebase. If it helps, here is my repo with the project: https://github.com/aleksanderbrymora/firebase-hooks-react/blob/FirebaseContext/src/firebase/context/CreateFirebaseContext.ts

The files in question are in `firebase/context/CreateFirebaseContext.ts`, `firebase/types/tech-array.ts`.

Also excuse my highly probably lack of organisation. I'm only starting out with TS and im yet to explore all the conventions. Feel free to note me on mistakes like that too.

Answer (score 0):

What TypeScript brings to JavaScript is static analysis: the ability to understand the types of values and objects, and catch type errors within the code itself. It then cuts all that stuff out of your code so that you're left with plain JavaScript, which you can then run. TypeScript is ultimately just JavaScript with static analysis added. You cannot 'run' TypeScript; the purpose of writing TypeScript is to transcompile it to JavaScript, and then run it. TypeScript is a compiler; everything it does is sorted before your code ever actually runs. That's what TypeScript is.

Which is to say: you cannot create a dynamic type based on the actual execution of your code, because types simply do not exist at runtime. That is just fundamentally not how this works.

I'm not across what's going on in your code, so I can't tell you what you should do instead. That said, if you have not yet looked at generics (see [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)), I think you should. Generics allow you to actually pass in a type to a function when you call it, letting you reference that type within the body of your function, and even in the arguments and return type.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, it does change how I think about it. I did have a look at generics and conditional types using `extends`, thats why I imported the types to attempt to do it, but now I get the fact that its fundamentaly wrong. 
Thanks for the answer!